# vscode jsx attribute completions aren't including the ="", only the attribute name

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, attributes, jsx

Normally when I make a jsx div and start typing "cl", a className autocomplete shows up and gives me className="" when I hit enter or tab. Now it only autocompletes to className. Same goes with any other attributes.

I have tried uninstalling all my extensions and even doing a fresh reinstall of vscode. In settings, jsx attribute completion style is set to auto.